# Can an owner who rents rooms write-off an unoccupied, unfinished basement that is open to all residents as a common area?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, rental-property, property-taxes, michigan

If a rental situation is owner-occupied and areas shared by lodgers and the owner are prorated for tax purposes, can an unfinished basement, treated as a common area to all equally, also be written-off on a pro-rata-share basis as a business expense?

**Additional detail:**

- Unfinished.
- Not a legal bedroom (nor to be used as one).
- It would simply be a common area to anyone who resides there for any purpose ie. recreation, storage, hiding from tornadoes, etc.
- In Michigan, USA

Comment: How do you account for kitchen access?

Comment: Do you have legal access to the basement, for example to store your things? This isn't quite clear to me from your edit. Also - does the basement have any specific costs associated, or are you talking about whether you need to apportion the allowed depreciation / utilities etc.?